# Create GIF from MP4 with PHP

Tags: php, ffmpeg, imagemagick, gif, mp4

I first started with installing FFMpeg and ImageMagick on my local server (`while ssh'd`).

I made some research, and thought that I can achieve Mp4->GIF with first, converting mp4 -> png and then, png -> gif.

So I tried running
`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -r 10 man/output%05d.png`. It created PNGs from Mp4 successfully. Then I tried running this php on localserver..

$ `php convertDoc.php`

```
$animatedGif = new Imagick();

$path = "./man/";

$files = scandir($path);

for($i=2;$i<6;$i++) {
    $image = new Imagick();
    var_dump($files);
    $image->readImage($path.$files[$i]);

    $animatedGif->addImage($image);
}

$animatedGif->writeImages('testOutput.gif', true);
```

But I started getting error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'no decode delegate for this image format

---

I checked `convert -list configure`. I have `DELEGATES bzlib mpeg fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lzma png ps tiff wmf x xml zlib`

Also I checked `identify -list format`. I have `PNG* rw- Portable Network Graphics (libpng 1.2.50)` *AND* `GIF* rw+ CompuServe graphics interchange format`

---

What am I doing wrong? Am I on the right way or completely out of track?

What is the most optimal way of generating GIFs from MP4 in PHP either using FFMpeg or Imagick, or both?

Comment: Try `php -i | grep -i magick` to see what your PHP interpreter knows about ImageMagick.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Should I check the supported formats? If so, it has both GIF and PNG in the list.

Comment: Why don't you just use `ffmpeg` to go from mp4 to gif?

Comment: Through php is faster? isn't it?

Comment: I doubt it, but I did not actually compare. First you have to wait for `ffmpeg` to output all of the PNG files, then from those files you use the Imagick extension to create the GIF. With `ffmpeg` alone you can avoid the intermediate PNG files (and Imagick) and output directly to GIF. See [How do I convert a video to GIF using ffmpeg, with reasonable quality?](http://superuser.com/a/556031/110524).